# Getting error in unit tests after implement Spring Security to project

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-security, mockito

I'm creating a project with Spring Boot and Spring Data Rest. I create unit tests for endpoints and after run everything pass. Then I implement Spring Security to my project: configuration, implement custom UserServiceDetails and password encoder. I test this using Postman and everything seems to work fine yet. Now I run my tests again and get an error. Of course, I secure my endpoints so I must get authorized in test to access it. After adding dependency spring-security-test and annotations for methods @WithMockUser, still getting same error as previous. It seems like Spring don't see my custom service (don't know why), but main problem is with Application Context.

Have idea to fix this?

#### InstructorRepositoryController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class InstructorRepositoryController {

    @Autowired
    private InstructorRepository instructorRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Value("${custom-page-size}")
    private int pageSize;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @GetMapping("/instructors")
    public Page<Instructor> getAll() {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0,pageSize);
        return instructorRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @GetMapping("/instructors/{id}")
    public Instructor getInstructorById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        return instructorRepository.findById(id).isPresent() ? instructorRepository.findById(id).get() : null ;
    }
}
```

#### InstructorRepositoryTest.java

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = InstructorRepositoryController.class)
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, RestDocumentationExtension.class})
@AutoConfigureRestDocs(outputDir = "target/generated-snippets")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class InstructorRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private InstructorRepositoryController instructorRepositoryController;

    private Instructor instructor;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext,
                      RestDocumentationContextProvider restDocumentation) {

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
                .build();
        instructor = new Instructor("firstName", "lastName");
        instructor.setId(1);
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "user", password = "user123", roles = "ADMIN")
    public void shouldReturnInstructorBasedOnId() throws Exception {
        //given
        given(instructorRepositoryController.getInstructorById(anyInt())).willReturn(instructor);
        //when+then
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/instructors/1")
                .contentType("application/json")).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().json(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(instructor)))
                .andDo(document("{methodName}",
                        preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
                        preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())));

        verify(instructorRepositoryController).getInstructorById(anyInt());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "user", password = "user123", roles = "ADMIN")
    public void shouldReturnAllInstructors() throws Exception {
        //given
        Instructor instructor2 = new Instructor("firstName2", "lastName3");
        Instructor instructor3 = new Instructor("firstName3", "lastName3");
        List<Instructor> instructors = Arrays.asList(instructor, instructor2, instructor3);
        Page<Instructor> instructorPage = new PageImpl<>(instructors);

        given(instructorRepositoryController.getAll()).willReturn(instructorPage);
        //when+then
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/instructors")
                    .contentType("application/json")).andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().json(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(instructorPage)))
                    .andDo(document("{methodName}",
                            preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
                            preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())));

        verify(instructorRepositoryController).getAll();
    }
}
```

#### SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/instructors").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/instructors/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

#### CustomUserDetailsService.java

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.findUserByUserName(username);

        if(user != null) {
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
                    user.getPassword(),
                    mapRolesToAuthority(user.getRoles()));
        }
        else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthority(List<Role> roles) {
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

#### Error when running every test

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userDetailsService in springboot.config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'springboot.services.CustomUserDetailsService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="customUserDetailsService")


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'springboot.services.CustomUserDetailsService' in your configuration.

2020-09-22 17:09:19.489 ERROR 18144 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@34129c78] to prepare test instance [springboot.resources.InstructorRepositoryTest@2d5a1588]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:95) ~[spring-boot-test-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79) ~[spring-boot-test-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54) ~[spring-boot-test-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:346) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1621) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:340) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:263) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:255) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'springboot.services.CustomUserDetailsService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="customUserDetailsService")}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) ~[spring-boot-test-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'springboot.services.CustomUserDetailsService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="customUserDetailsService")}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1717) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 83 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Is it possible for your to share your code in a git repo or as zip?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Here: https://github.com/PeterStuck/spring-security-with-jwt

Comment: Thanks, I'm taking a look.

Comment: I cannot run your app as it is. Getting `Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration ............ ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.hateoas.server.LinkRelationProvider`

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure if you make your test `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@WebMvcTest`, it should fix the bean initialization error.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I spend a lot of time to fix this. Thanks a lot for your time to look at it. I appreciate it. Regrads!